# Receiving window keyword with JSON request using jQuery

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, getjson

**Client side javascript:**

```
var headFiles = {
  Admin:{
    JS:"/Path/to/file.js",
    CSS:"/Path/to/file.css"
  }
};

$.getJSON(URL_TO_SERVER, function (data) {
  //My code here
});
```

**Server side code:**

```
Response.ContentType = "text/json"
```

Text been sent:

```
Response.Write("{" &
    """HTML"":""/cms/includes/admin_content.aspx"", " &
    """CSS_JS"":[" &
        "{""Admin_JS"": headFiles.Admin.JS }," &
        "{""Admin_CSS"": headFiles.Admin.CSS }" &
      "]" &
    "}")
```

$.getJSON fails to receive response. I have tried $.ajax also. I have tried setting ContentType to "text/plain" also. 
The issue is that I am using javascript variable "headFiles" in the JSON, which is not been parsed.

Any idea how to send javascript variable as a part of JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `second parameter` of `getJSON` like,

```
$.getJSON(URL_TO_SERVER,{headFiles: headFiles}, function (data) {
  //My code here
});
```

And try this on **server side**

```
Response.Write('{"HTML":"/cms/includes/admin_content.aspx","CSS_JS":[{"Admin_JS":"headFiles.Admin.JS" },{"Admin_CSS": "headFiles.Admin.CSS"}]}');
```

check your json is valid or not

```
{"HTML":"/cms/includes/admin_content.aspx","CSS_JS":[{"Admin_JS":"headFiles.Admin.JS" },{"Admin_CSS": "headFiles.Admin.CSS"}]}
```

**above json** is **valid tested** on http://jsonlint.com/

Read [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: I think I was not understandable to you. I am having issue while receiving data from server, not sending it to server. Server is sending javascript variable as a part of JSON.

Comment: I have updated my server side code in the question itself. As per my understanding issue is that JSON doesn't allow anything without double quotes, except numbers. And I am trying to use javascript variable.

Comment: Bottom line is that I can't use variables in JSON.